# Change the icon of a file with a .application extension

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm building an application in vb.net/visual studio 2012. When I publish my application, the .exe file and some other files are uploaded to a server.

Publishing my application also generates a `.application` file. I can use this file to search for updates on my server and to automatically open the latest version of my application.

I want to change the icon of this file to the icon of my .exe file, but I don't know how. Is there any way of changing the icon of this file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps:

1. Right click on the application name in the `solution explorer`
2. Select properties
3. Now you can see [image: window]
4. now select Application---> change `default icon` to `<..Browse..>`
5. it will opens a new window from their you can browse apropriate `.ico` file and then publish the application

Comment: This will change the icon of the exe, not the .application file

Comment: I've done that already, but that only changes the icon for the .exe file

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the icon of the `.application` file, is not set by visual studio. It is the icon of the application that opens `.application` files: ClickOnce Application Deployment Support Library.

If I change the icon of that application, it will only change on my own pc and it will change the icon of all my `.application` files to the same one. So I think there is no solution.

Thanks anyway!